# GDB crash when debugging QT TimerEvent

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, qt-creator

---

### **Issue**

I am having difficulty debugging inside of my application's timerEvent functions. While the application is able to run, if I set a breakpoint inside of even something as simple as the following, I receive an error message stating: "The gdb process crashed."

```
void MyClass::timerEvent (QTimerEvent *e) {
    std::cout << "TIMER!";
}
```

I have included a debugger log [here](http://pastebin.com/WSSh8CNV) via pastebin.

---

### **Attempts**

To try and fix this, I tried upgrading gdb iteratively with each version of QT-creator to no avail.

I am using:

- Linux ubuntu-x86 2.6.32-42-generic #95-Ubuntu 10.04LTS SMP i686 GNU/Linux
- QT creator (versions 2.4 through 2.5.2)
- gdb (7.1 through 7.5) targeting "x86-linux-generic-elf-32bit"
- pythongdb (7.2)

---

### **Questions**

My questions are twofold, namely:

- What is causing gdb to crash?

and

- What can I do to make it work?

Failing that, I wonder: Where else should I look for more details of the crash?

---

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning it. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your QT libraries are up to date. Even though a new QT-creator will install via the handy-dandy .bin file they provide, it was built using the newer QT libraries, and expects them to be in place. If they are not, well...

Additionally, if you are not installing gdb into one of the standard directories where QT-creator can find it, make sure you add it manually to your toolchains via tools->options->build and run->toolchains.